# Factoring Algebraic Expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

Say I have an expression

$$x = L-(L-N)y^2(1+AB)$$

is there a way I can use mathematica to put the expression into the form

$$x = M(1+\sigma B)$$

where $M$ and $\sigma$ are lumped terms?

Comment: example please?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment as you'll need to be more specific as to what you need in general.  (Also, in *Mathematica* you should avoid single capital letters for variable names especially `N` and `D`.)  For example, is what you're look for deals only with equations linear in powers of `B`?  Or is it just solving for `M` and $\sigma$ in this particular case?

If it's just this particular case, then the following is one way to do so:

```
f = CoefficientList[L - (L - n) y^2 (1 + a b), b]
(* {L+(-L+n) y^2,-a (L-n) y^2} *)

m = f[[1]]
(* L+(-L+n) y^2 *)

σ = f[[2]]/f[[1]]
(* -((a (L-n) y^2)/(L+(-L+n) y^2)) *)
```